# Sequelize Wrong query? findargs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, sequelize.js

The picture on the right is the MongoDB code, and the picture on the left is the Sequelize code. console.log(findArgs) is printed, and there is no error in the front-end part, but findArgs does not work.
findArgs is the filtering part.

Sequelize code doesn't work. I think the underlined part is wrong, but I don't know.

It responds to the backend router by pressing the key value, but not to the UI.

MongoDB code

```
router.post('/AllLists', (req, res) => {
   
  let limit = req.body.limit ? parseInt(req.body.limit) : 20;  
  let skip = req.body.skip ? parseInt(req.body.skip) : 0; 
  let findArgs = {};

  for(let key in req.body.filters) { 
    if (req.body.filters[key].length > 0) { // continet or price 
      console.log('key', key)
      findArgs[key] = req.body.filters[key];
      }
    }
    console.log(findArgs)
    
    Product.find(findArgs)
    .populate("writer") 
    .skip(skip) 
    .limit(limit) 
    .exec((err, productInfo) => {
      if(err) return res.status(400).json({ success: false, err })
    
      return res.status(200).json({
         success: true, productInfo,
      postSize: productInfo.length 
    }) 
  })
})
```

Sequelize code

```
router.post('/AllLists', async (req, res, next ) => {
    let limit = req.body.limit ? parseInt(req.body.limit) : 20;
    let skip = req.body.skip ? parseInt(req.body.skip) : 0; 
    let findArgs = {};

    for(let key in req.body.filters) {
        if(req.body.filters[key].length > 0) {
            findArgs[key] = req.body.filters[key];
        }
    }
    console.log('findArgs', findArgs);
    try {
        const productInfo = await Product.findAll({
            findArgs,
            limit: limit,
            offset: skip,
            include: [
                {
                    model: Image,
                    attributes: ['src']
                },
                
            ],
        });
        res.status(200).json({ success: true,  productInfo, postSize: productInfo.length});
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        next(err);
    }
})
```

Output to the backend router. When the key value is pressed

```
findArgs { Brand: [ 2 ] }
```

Is the findArgs query wrong in Sequelize?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to understand the sequelize is ORM(Object Relational Mapping) which is used only for Relational Database(MySQL, Postgres, etc).

for MongoDB which is a non-relation database, you can use mongoose ODM(Object Document Mapping)